# JavaScript DOM methods inserting new lines

Tags: javascript, html

This is my desired UI:

```
+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |
+----+----+----+ 
|    |    |    |
+----+----+----+
```

This can be achieved by printing HTML as follows:

```
<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
```

Printing HTML like this:

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Results in:

```
+----++----++----+
|    ||    ||    |
+----++----++----+
+----++----++----+ 
|    ||    ||    |
+----++----++----+
```

If you can visualize it, the issue above is that the `div` elements are not flush with one another. This is due to the whitespace between them in the HTML being displayed.

So here is the problem:

```
 for(i=0;i<6;i++)
     document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
```

Produces the latter.

How can I produce the former without setting `font-size` to 0?

Comment: Given your `.appendChild()` code, I wouldn't think there would be an issue. There should be no text nodes in between the divs.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figured. I'm going to debug some more to make damn sure it isn't a CSS issue.

Comment: I see no space between them in my test: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/edet81m9/2/ but they're also not put into rows. Can you make a Stack Snippet that shows what you're doing?

Comment: I'm just awesome -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/63ozw96k/

Comment: @EvanHendler Just make the margin set to 0 and it will work. check out the box model.

Comment: Lmao @adeneo. I'm gunna hack around with this a little bit. It's tough to post a snip of it because I'm writing my own PHP framework that obfuscates literally everything. I'll find the answer and share it when I do.

Comment: Did you use a [reset](http://cssreset.com/)

Comment: That's actually a legitimate question: no. I noticed that the `div`s work, but it's the `a`s that seem to have an issue.

Comment: I found the issue - the `<a>` tags had no innerHTML. They stacked with space between them because they were empty.

Comment: Heh, that's why providing a link to a working instance of your code is a good idea, we couldn't have helped you even if we wanted to.

Comment: Yeah, someday I'll be a responsible adult :)

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS should be:

```
.div {
    float: left;
    width: 33.333333333333333%;
}
```

also making sure they have no `margin`, `padding`, or `border`, because these properties affect the width of your element.

If you want them to have one of these three properties then read up about the [CSS box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model).

TL;DR hint, this snippet at the top of your CSS will make the width and height properties of your elements behave like you'd normally expect them to if you're new to CSS:

```
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-model: border-box;
}
html {
    box-model: inherit;
}
```